# What is the most efficient way to write out my Pig Latin converter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a pig Latin sentence converter and was wondering if I could make my code any smaller. Pig Latin is basically like if a word starts with a vowel then ad yay to the end of the word. If the word starts with a consonant then take the first letter and put it at the end of the word and then add ay to it.
Example: apple = appleyay & tree = reetay

```
string_name =input('Enter String: ').lower().strip()
string_name =string_name.split()
pig_sentence =[]

for word in string_name:
    if word[0] in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
        pig_word =word+'yay'
        pig_sentence.append(pig_word)
    else:
        pig_word =word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
        pig_sentence.append(pig_word)

pig_sentence =' '.join(pig_sentence)    
print(pig_sentence)
```

Comment: This sounds like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ "Code Review is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code."

Comment: "pig_sentence.append(pig_word)" is executed at the end of both if-branches so it can be moved after the if-else-block. Apart from that smaller code or less lines is not always better. It may reduce readability and maintainability of the code.

Comment: Typically, pig latin moves all starting consonants (tree -> eetray).

Comment: Why would you want to make it smaller?

Comment: Pig latin in Python [has been done before](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=pig+latin+%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq), you may want to look at how others did it and what the reactions were on their entries instead of getting your own code reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

The following should also work.

```
print(" ".join([word+"yay" if word[0] in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] else word[1:] + word[0] + "ay" for word in input('Enter String: ').lower().strip().split()]))
```

But, as you can see, this example isn't very readable. You might also want to use:

```
string_name =input('Enter String: ').lower().strip()
string_name =string_name.split()

pigsentence=" ".join([word+"yay" if word[0] in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] else word[1:] + word[0] + "ay" for word in string_name])
print(pigsentence)
```

or just continue using the code you've now, as shorter code isn't always better, and you don't need to really worry about efficiency.